# Merge two pictures in PHP

Tags: php, gd

I need to combine two images in PHP. Master picture is in PNG, secondary in JPG.

First picture:

[image: master]
<sub>(source: [grafikstudio-m.com](https://happywin.konektor.grafikstudio-m.com/imageMerge/muster.png))</sub>

Secondary picture:

[image: second]
<sub>(source: [grafikstudio-m.com](https://happywin.konektor.grafikstudio-m.com/imageMerge/test.jpg))</sub>

Test:
http://happywin.konektor.grafikstudio-m.com/imageMerge/

```php
<?php
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('muster.png');
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg("test.jpg");

imagecolortransparent($src);
imagesavealpha($dest, false);

imagealphablending($src, true);
imagesavealpha($src, true);


imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, -100, 2000, 1300, 50);



header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

I need the pictures to be connected and with a white background

Comment: What do you actually want to happen? Could you mock up an image with the correct contents?

Comment: Try removing all the alpha channel statements.

Answer (score 0):

Create a canvas image with same size as muster.png and fill it with white color.

```
$muster = imagecreatefrompng('muster.png');
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($muster), imagesy($muster));
$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, $white);
```

Open test.jpg and use the top-left pixel color as the transparent color.

```
$test = imagecreatefromjpeg('test.jpg');
imagecolortransparent($test, imagecolorallocate($test, 255, 255, 255));
```

Copy the 2 images to the canvas, the order is optional, notice that copy muster.png (truecolor) with `imagecopy` but copy test.jpg (pallete) with `imagecopymerge`.

```
imagecopy($canvas, $muster, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($muster), imagesy($muster));
imagecopymerge($canvas, $test, 0, 100, 0, 0, imagesx($test), imagesy($test), 100);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($canvas);

// ...destroy
```